# Apache+mod_ftp - how to set up FTP without altering "/" directory?

Tags: apache-http-server, ftp

I have a WAMP on Apache 2.2 configured, up and running, now I have to add FTP functionality to it. Apparently the only solution that's available without compiling is mod_ftp, and good thing the server isn't 2.4, as I've read that precompiled mod_ftp is not compatible with it. So, I've ran into a need of modifying `<Directory />` section in httpd.conf file to allow at least a subnet for FTP connection like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from <classified>
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

The default config is "Deny from all" and no `AllowOverride`. My question is - is it necessary to fix `<Directory />` section for FTP to actually work, and what else can I do in order to leave the default configuration intact?

Comment: For a reason unknown, the very same question got put on hold at serverfault, so if this site is not the place to ask it, kindly say where I can ask such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to wrap FTP settings in a separate `VirtualHost` section, and I could place desired settings in `<Directory />` section within it to make my FTP server work as intended without loosening security on HTTP part.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:21>
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from <classified>
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Even if I made mistakes in `Order`, this allowed users to connect and do their work.